# Wiring the LED of a 220V push button

Tags: led, switches

I have just bought the following 5-pin switches of eBay: [here](https://www.ebay.de/itm/16mm-metal-push-button-switch-power-button-Waterproof-Flat-circular-button-LED/293504536465?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=592307561720&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)
[image: 5-pin switch]

Problem is that no spec came with it and I am now wondered if I can directly wire the LED pins to the main or if I need to add extra electronics.

Comment: Why don't you ask the seller? If there is no info how to use it, why did you buy it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wiring a 5 Pin LED Switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242193/wiring-a-5-pin-led-switch)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, not really, I did read this thread before posting my thread, thanks :-)

Comment: Ok, I retracted my closing/duplicate vote. Better ask the seller as said above.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, yes that is the first thing I did, but I have not received any answer yet :-)

Comment: You can try to find a similar google circuit, and test conductivity between pins with a multimeter.

Comment: [What to check for when buying an electronic component or module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504044/what-to-check-for-when-buying-an-electronic-component-or-module).

Comment: Ebay says: **LED Voltage: Please choose the right Voltage in option** - so what option did you choose when you placed the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LED voltage is part of the ordering options, so if you selected 220VAC, and they got the order right, that should be the correct voltage.

Comment: Ok, great, so I should be fine then. It would be a shame to blow it up :-)

Comment: Chances are still non-zero.

Comment: Ok, I wired the 2 LED pins directly to the main and it did not blow up, yeah! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The seller provided the wiring diagram. I am adding it as an answer as I believe it may help other people to understand how these swtches work.
[image]
[image]